# bash bcmath functions

Tags: bash, bcmath

I have two functions for GNU bc in a Bash script.

```
BC_CEIL="define ceil(x) { if (x>0) { if (x%1>0) return x+(1-(x%1)) else return x } else return -1*floor(-1*x) }\n"
BC_FLOOR="define floor(x) { if (x>0) return x-(x%1) else return -1*ceil(-1*x) }\n"
echo -e "scale=2"$BC_CEIL$BC_FLOOR"ceil(2.5)" | bc
```

Both functions work fine in interactive bc. bc does not seem to allow multiple functions on one line separated by ; though, so I have to echo -n | bc with newlines at the end of each function. The above output is 2.5, not the expected 3.0 that I get if I type it into bc -i myself. It seems that bash calls bc for each line of echo output, rather than echo'ing it all to a single instance. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I get 2.5 interactively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale needs to be zero for `x%1` to work. You should normally only have one return from a function.

```
define ceil(x) { auto savescale; savescale = scale; scale = 0; if (x>0) { if (x%1>0) result = x+(1-(x%1)) else result = x } else result = -1*floor(-1*x);  scale = savescale; return result }
define floor(x) { auto savescale; savescale = scale; scale = 0; if (x>0) result = x-(x%1) else result = -1*ceil(-1*x);  scale = savescale; return result }
```

This needs a newline after the scale statement:

```
echo -e "scale=2\n"$BC_CEIL$BC_FLOOR"ceil(2.5)" | bc
```

Comment: The missing \n after scale was a typo after editing the copy-pasted code.

I find different return statements in if/else blocks easier to read than a variable written everywhere and returned once, but in this case - since scale must be reset - a single return makes sense.

Comment: @Gordon: Very nice. It doesn't make much sense to me that `bc` wouldn't have an int() built in or in its `-l` library. (Or floor/ceiling for that matter.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe `1.` is incorrect. 
The `if()` comparison needs to be   `X >= 0` .

I find this works

```
define ceil(x) {                         
    if (x >= 0) { if (x%1>0) return x+(1-(x%1)) else return x } 
    else return -1*floor(-1*x)               
}
define floor(x) {                        
    if (x >= 0) return x-(x%1)               
    else return -1*ceil(-1*x)                
}
```